# How do I prevent duplicate table names when using cross join?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables in a SQL database:

```
t_customers
   ID_operator int primary key auto_incr
   firstname   varchar(30)
   lastname    varchar(30)
   email       varchar(100)


t_operator
   ID_operator int primary key auto_incr
   firstname   varchar(30)
   lastname    varchar(30)
   course      varchar(10)
```

I have another table, which represents an order, in which I join both fields when querying another field:

```
SELECT 
    *, // table t_orders
    t_customers.firstname, 
    t_customers.lastname, 
    t_operator.firstname AS operator_firstname, 
    t_operator.lastname AS operator_lastname 
FROM 
    t_orders 
CROSS JOIN 
    t_customers, t_operator 
WHERE 
    id_orders IS 1;
```

I have tried to alleviate this by using the `AS` keyword and the new fields do get added, but I still have 2 fields named "firstname" and "lastname" in my query, preventing me from working with it correctly. Is there any solution besides renaming the tables?

Comment: Huh?  Why are you using a `CROSS JOIN`?  Sample data and desired results would really help.  Why don't you have `JOIN` conditions?

Comment: Try to name your colomn with the correct way, I like to do cust_firstname, op_firstname, etc ...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am really fairly new to this and thought this is the way to do it. I basically want to resolve my foreign keys to the real data.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
SELECT o.*, // table t_orders
       c.firstname, c.lastname, 
       op.firstname AS operator_firstname, 
       op.lastname AS operator_lastname 
FROM t_orders o JOIN
     t_customers c
     ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer JOIN
     t_operator op
     ON c.id_operator = c.id_operator
WHERE id_orders = 1;
```

Comment: Correct answer. Because in origin query `*` shows all columns from all tables. So, one field from `*` and one from `t_customers.firstname`. `o.*` shows columns only from `t_orders` table.

Comment: @IvanBurlutskiy . . . List the columns that you want explicitly.